# How to get the correct accuracy with big integer division in python

Tags: python, bignum

I have a big integer below, as 'max'.  How come the value dividing max by '27' is not equivalent to just completely omiting the first number '27'.  Technically they should be equal, but in python they are not.  How can I get the same answer by dividing the max value with '27', in this example?

```
max = 27*37*47*30*17*6*20*17*21*43*5*49*49*50*20*42*45*1*22*44
no27 = 37*47*30*17*6*20*17*21*43*5*49*49*50*20*42*45*1*22*44
div27 = (max/27)
modno27 = no27%40
moddiv27 = div27%40
```

The values printed are:

```
no27 = 35882855955274315680000000
div27 = 3.5882855955274316e+25
modno27 = 0
moddiv27 = 8.0
```

Answer (score 13):

Assuming this is Python 3, you used true division, which computes `float` results, but `float` (based on C `double`) has representation limitations that Python `int`s do not (above ~`2**53`, it can't represent every integer value).

When you know the number is evenly divisible, use `//` to preserve `int`-ness. If it's not evenly divisible, you'll round down, e.g. `5 // 3 == 1`. If that's unacceptable, you can use `divmod` to compute both quotient and remainder at once (so no information is lost) or the `fractions.Fraction` type or `decimal.Decimal` type (with appropriate precision) to get more precise results in a single result type.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  Thank you for the thorough explanation of what was going on.